# How to get the HTMl page of redirected page using HttpURLConnection with Jsoup

Tags: android

I am trying to get the html page of the redirected page using HttpURLConnection. The initial page is login and I am getting redirected from that to the next page. I am also getting the URL of the newly directed page also but when I get the html content of the newly directed page it returns the login page html view. The code is below plz help out.

```
 protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
        try {
 old URL--->URL url = new URL(UrlLink);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            List<NameValuePair> login = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            login.add(new BasicNameValuePair("login", "xxxxx"));
            login.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "yyyyyy"));
            login.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Login", "Login"));
            login.clear();
            int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println(responseCode);
            urlConnection.connect();
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
New Url---> URL newURL = urlConnection.getURL();
            String urlNew=   newURL.toString();
Returns-->  doc = Jsoup.connect(urlNew).get();
Login page  Elements docEle = doc.select("#header a");
 HTML       Log.v("Document", docEle.toString() );
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v("Error", e.toString());
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure that the cookies are stored properly after the log in?

Comment: How to check for cookies I dont know.

Answer (score 0):

To set VM-wide cookie (in memory), use the code below:

```
CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);
```

Then after loggin in, you need to pass the cookie to Jsoup, something like the below example (modify as needed for you case)

```
Jsoup.connect("https://need.authentication.com").cookie(urlNew, cookie).get()
```